# Закрытие рабочих потоков при возникновении ошибки

Tags: java, алгоритм, многопоточность

В моем приложении следующая ситуация: есть `тред типа А` и множество `тредов типа Б`, помимо этого есть основной тред. В треде А возникает ошибка, после чего наобходимо сразу, или как можно быстрее закрыть все треды Б и основной тред, либо закрыть треды Б и передать управление в основной тред, который по какому-то флагу должен понять что произошло и сделать некоторые действия перед закрытием приложения. Треды Б необходимо закрыть как можно быстрее, потому как в них запускаются ресурсоемкие процессы, запуск которых становиться бессмысленым в случае ошибки в треде А.

Может кто-то из опытных разработчиков подсказать новичку вариант алгоритма (желательно с примером), когда все это было бы возможно без использования `System.exit()`?

Comment: Вам, кажется, нужно просто взять actor-based фреймворк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чего тут алгоритмы придумывать? Если вы пользуетесь чистыми `Thread`, то рекомендую глянуть в пакет `java.util.concurrent` в сторону `ExecutorService` и т.п.
В частности, в вашей задаче вы можете запустить в одном `Executor` поток A, а в другом потоки Б, отлавливать ошибку выполнения потока А, и если она произошла, то просто закрывать `Executor` с потоками Б (вызывать `shutdownNow`).

**UPD**

```
class A implements Runnable {
    public void run(){}
}

class B implements Runnable {
    public void run(){}
}
```

И схематичный набросок как это работает:

```
ExecutorService executorA = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ExecutorService executorB = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<?> futureA = executorA.submit(new A());
List<Future<?>> futuresB = new ArrayList<>();
for(...){
    futuresB.add(executorB.submit(new B()));
}
try {
    futureA.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //process
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    executorB.shutdownNow();
    //or
    //futuresB.forEach(f -> f.cancel(true));
    //executorB.shutdown();
}
executorA.shutdown();
//futuresB.forEach(f -> f.get());
```

Comment: Ну и не забываем все операции с портами и прочими ресурсами проводить в конструкции try-catch-finally, где в блоке finally пробуем закрыть порт, если он всё же открылся.

Comment: Пока не совсем понял как применить к моему случаю. Дело в том, что у меня тред А запускается, чтобы проверить наличие авторизации и при необходимости ее установить, и только после 10 секундной паузы после этого запускаются треды Б. Между тем тред А продолжает бежать и раз в 30 минут вновь проверяет авторизацию и при необходимости устанавливает ее, и в случае ошибки при попытке авторизации и выдает ошибку, при которой и надо остановить треды Б.

Comment: Другими словами понятно как закрывать Executor с потоками Б, но не понятно где и как я должен отлавливать ошибку потока А.